# Get un retrieved rows only in DB2 select

Tags: db2

I have an BPM application where I am polling some rows from DB2 database at every 5 mins with a scheduler R1 with below query - 
- select * from Table where STATUS = 'New'

based on rows returned I do some processing and then change the status of these rows to 'Read'.

But while this processing is being completed, its takes more than 5 mins and in meanwhile scheduler R1 runs and picks up some of the cases already picked up in last run.

How can I ensure that every scheduler picks up the rows which were not selected in last run. What changes do i need to do in my select statement? Please hep.

Comment: Which type of server are you using: DB2 for i, z/OS, or LUW? Any idea why your process, which runs every 5 mins, takes longer than 5 mins to run?

Comment: I am using DB2 on Windows, based on rows returned I have some processing to be done in BPM which can take any amount of time to complete, but still I have to ensure that next running schedular should not pick up the rows already picked up by previous scheduler.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I ensure that every scheduler picks up the rows which were not selected in last run

You will need to make every scheduler aware of what was selected by other schedulers. You can do this, for example, by locking the selected rows (`SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`). Of course, you will then need to handle lock timeouts.

Another option, allowing for better concurrency, would be to update the record status *before* processing the records. You might introduce an intermediary status, something like `'In progress'`, and include the status in the query condition.

Comment: +1 on 2nd option. Update all 'NEW' to 'RDY' or something similar. Query the 'RDY' records to process.  Update 'RDY' records as done.    Repeat.